# Published an app to the Google Play Store and the API call does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play

I have an app which uses Unsplash API. The app works fine when I download it directly from Android Studio. But when I download it from the Google Play Store, the API doesn't work. What is it that went wrong? Thanks guys.

Here's how its supposed to look

[image]

And here's how it looks when you download it from google play

[image]

Comment: You have not provided any code, anything. How are we supposed to help? Btw, you might wanna check permissions. Also, one way would be to compare the APKs that you download from Google Play vs what you already have. To my knowledge, they shouldn't be any different.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It was on my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the problem, it was on my end. I had to change the package name for my project in order to upload it to the play store. I didn't refactor it properly, thus having a blank screen. Me being in a rush, forgot to run my project after the package name changes, so i didn't see the app before I released it...